# URL Signing with AWS Cloudfront - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

My main purpose is to sign the URL using AWS Cloudfront in Ruby

I Have created a key pair at https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials (Key Pairs tab). Which provided with a key pair id and a pem file (save the pem file in your project dir).

In your AWS Cloudfront portal, create a distribution. Selected "yes" for Restrict Bucket Access.

Click No for Grant Read Permissions on Bucket.

Create the distribution.

In S3 bucket, i am using a file that is not public. i.e. no read permissions. In this case, we will test this against sample.png.

```
url = "https://actual_cdn_id_here.cloudfront.net/sample.png"
key_pair_id = 'your_aws_key_pair_id'
expires_in = 1.minute

expires = (Time.now.getutc + expires_in).to_i.to_s

private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('private_key_file.pem'))

 policy = %Q[{"Statement":[{"Resource":"#{url}","Condition": 
 {"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":#{expires}}}}]}]                                                                     
 signature =   Base64.strict_encode64(private_key.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, policy))

 "#{url}?Expires=#{expires}&Signature=#{signature}&Key-Pair-
  Id=#{key_pair_id}"
```

But still after generating, I am getting the following error

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidKey</Code>
  <Message>Unknown Key</Message>
</Error>
```

Where I am doing wrong? I have even added the Trusted Signers and made self for the same.

Comment: Check the response headers.  Do you see `Server: Amazon S3`?  If so, verify that you have the Origin Access Identity selected in the Origin settings, and a bucket policy allowing access to the bucket from that origin access identity.

Comment: This is my bucket policy which I have in S3 bucket. My OAI is E1E3N3VD1MH57U. Is that my policy is right?
`{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E1E3N3VD1MH57U"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mcds_staging_fulltext/*"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Was this auto-created for you?  Does this match the OAI that's configured for this origin, on the Origins tab in CloudFront?

Comment: Yes, this has been auto created in S3. I checked only this identity E1E3N3VD1MH57U which yes it matches the identity in Oigins tab.